# Change the fill of all elements inside an svg using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, fill

I would like to change the fill color of all elements inside an SVG. The elements are both type rect and polygon. I have not set a default color.

Here is a sample file:

http://www.kingoslo.com/instruments/test.svg

How can I do this most elegantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have jQuery:

```
$('svg').children().css('fill', '#ffffff');
```

EDIT: Note that this assumes the rects and polygons are the direct children of the svg element.

Comment: I think this is elegant.Thanks.M

Answer (score 1):

Another variant similar to the one by Robert Longson:

```
document.documentElement.style.fill = 'blue';
```

I prefer documentElement over rootElement because it's in DOM Core, and they're mostly the same.

Comment: I've removed my answer because rootElement is deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me while working with a complex SVG having a lot of nested elements:

`$('svg').find('path, text').css('fill', '#ffffff')`